# Creating an interactive map with wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I 'm in the research stage to create a interactive map like http://www.locksmithdirectory.com/ ! using themes or plugins !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try to use the Google Geochart API to create a similar map. It allows to create interactive maps and to capture click events. You can find more information and examples here: https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart

I created a plugin for WordPress that uses this API. It integrates all the needed scripts and allows to build a map from the admin panel. You can find more information here: http://meisterpixel.com/interactive-map-builder/